# Teechart Axis scroll bar tool

Tags: activex, teechart

I Installed new Teechart 2015 ActiveX control, I was searching in tool as found there is an axis scroll bar tool, Which I want to use. but when I add it too my chart I am  not able to scroll the data it remains constant.

Please let me where I have to define the range for the same.

Thanks
Akshay

Answer (score 2):

answer is present in teechart fourm :- http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=14569&p=64234&hilit=axis+scroll&sid=7d69e31f2871e932353ac232d904fb29#p64234